# WPF MVVM DataGrid Navigation

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I'd like ask for help with this problem.
My goal is prepare navigation control for datagrid same like in WinForms.
Move top, move one row down, one row up, move bottom and possibility jump to row (by number).

I make some solution xaml:

```
        <GroupBox x:Name="gbInfo" 
                  BorderBrush="Black" 
                  BorderThickness="1" 
                  Margin="4" 
                  Header="Info">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Button Content="&lt;&lt;" 
                        Command="{Binding CmdMoveUpDown}" 
                        CommandParameter="Down"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding InfoTable}" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Button Content="&gt;&gt;" 
                        Command="{Binding CmdMoveUpDown}" 
                        CommandParameter="Up"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </GroupBox> 
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgrForPrijem"  
                  Margin="5" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding TabulkaPrijmu}" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                  AlternationCount="2"  
                  SelectionMode="Single
                  CanUserAddRows="False" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem}" 
                  IsReadOnly="True" >
        <intr:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <atch:ScrollIntoViewBahaviour/>
        </intr:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name ="dgtcForDpr" 
                                Header="ID Car"  
                                Width="80*" 
                                Binding="{Binding DPR}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dgtcForIdDpr" 
                                Header="Type of Car" 
                                Width="40*" 
                                Binding="{Binding ID_DPR}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dgtcForIdStav" 
                                Header="Status" 
                                Width="60*" 
                                Binding="{Binding ID_STAV}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

And here is view model :

```
public class VMIndexMaterialIncome : ViewModelBase
{

    public VMIndexMaterialIncome()
    {

        TabulkaPrijmu = new ObservableCollection<TMaterialIncome>(new MaterialSupplyServices().ProvideAllMaterialIncomes());
    }

    private TMaterialIncome mySelectedItem;
    public TMaterialIncome MySelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return mySelectedItem;
        }
        set
        {
            mySelectedItem = value;
            InfoTable = TabulkaPrijmu.IndexOf(mySelectedItem).ToString();
            NotifyPropertyChanged("MySelectedItem");
        }
    }


    private string infoTable;

    public string InfoTable
    {
        get { return infoTable; }
        set
        {
            infoTable = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("InfoTable");
        }
    }



    public ICommand CmdMoveUpDown
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand<object>((object obj) =>
            {
                if (TabulkaPrijmu != null)
                {
                    int myIndex = TabulkaPrijmu.IndexOf(MySelectedItem);
                    switch(obj.ToString())
                    {
                        case "Up":
                            if (myIndex < (TabulkaPrijmu.Count - 1))
                                myIndex++;
                            break;
                        case "Down":
                            if (myIndex > 0)
                                myIndex--;
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }

                    MySelectedItem = TabulkaPrijmu[myIndex];
                }
            });
        }

    }


    private ObservableCollection<TMaterialIncome> tabulkaPrijmu;
    public ObservableCollection<TMaterialIncome> TabulkaPrijmu
    {
        get
        {
            return tabulkaPrijmu;
        }

        set
        {
            tabulkaPrijmu = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TabulkaPrijmu");
        }
    }
 }
}
```

And here scrollBehaviour code :

```
    public class ScrollIntoViewBahaviour : Behavior<DataGrid>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        this.AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged);
    }
    void AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is DataGrid)
        {
            DataGrid grid = (sender as DataGrid);
            if (grid.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                Action action = delegate () {
                    grid.UpdateLayout();
                    grid.ScrollIntoView(grid.SelectedItem, null);
                    grid.Focus(); // added this to make it focus to the grid
                };
                grid.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action);
            }
        }
    }
    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        this.AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -=
            new SelectionChangedEventHandler(AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged);
    }
}
```

All is working - when I click button -> Selected row is move up or down.
But when I sort datagrid by clicking column header. Functionality is wrong.
In case ObservableCollection have different order (sort) and datagrid have different order.

Is any option to sort ObservableCollection after click header (according selected column) ?
And of course do it with no code behind ? Due to MVVM pattern ?

Thank you for help.

Comment: what exactly is the problem when u try to sort ?

Comment: I sort datagrid. All rows are sorted. But when I click 1st row (in datagrid) its for example 30 item in observable collection - indexOf(SelectedItem) is 30 .